# MYSQL query using OR and AND on same sentence

Tags: mysql, subquery, case, exists

I need help writing a query that will validate a first expression and than, if its true, will validate the following expression. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  name 
FROM 
  names 
WHERE 
  (tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 2) AND (tag_id = 3 OR tag_id = 4)
```

Tried to use subqueries with if's and exists, but no success.

Any help? Thanks,

Comment: Your logic does not make any sense here. `tag_id` cannot satisfy both conditions of the `AND` simultaneously. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, perhaps including sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines a bit, perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT n1.name
    FROM names n1
        INNER JOIN names n2
            ON n1.name = n2.name
    WHERE (n1.tag_id = 1 OR n1.tag_id = 2)
        AND (n2.tag_id = 3 OR n2.tag_id = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but seems this is not working on my query, I already got plenty of joins. Is there a way to mysql validate 1 expression and if its true validate the next?

Comment: @Henrique: As I mentioned in my comment on the question, you need to do a better job of explaining the problem you're trying to solve. Adding sample data and expected results to your question would go a long way towards that end.

Comment: I understand, seems your logic is correct but script is kinda complicated to explain briefly. I will work on that logic. Thanks